# Is there such a thing as a JSON blob which has categorized *numerous* sites in a meaningful way?

Tags: database, json, categories

I have a huge list of URLs in a database table. From these, I am able to extract the "domain", such as "stackexchange.com" or "bbc.co.uk".

I'd like to be able to get some standardized "category" label for each of these domains.

This means I'm looking for some kind of free resource online which has something like this:

```
[
    'stackexchange.com': 'Q&A service',
    'bbc.co.uk': 'News',
    ...
]
```

(I forget exactly what JSON syntax looks like since I always let my JSON parser deal with the parsing to a more native format.)

Is there such a thing? Perhaps it's provided by Mozilla or something for some kind of categorization project used in some way by Firefox, which I can "hook into"?